# Simulating a button press with another button press

Tags: android, kotlin

I currently want to have a button that when I press it another button flashes as if it has been pressed at the same time and activates the function of the other button. My current code is as such:

```
fun onTwo(view: View) {
            button1.callOnClick()
            button1.isPressed = true
                    }
```

However the issue I am facing is that it freezes button1 as if it is pressed until it is pressed again. Anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: please post a complete, minimal example for this question so that others can recreate it

Answer (score 1):

You could add listener in one of the button to check for clicks and then use that event to trigger click event in another button, like this:

```kotlin
val button1 = findViewById(R.id.btn1ID) as Button
button1.setOnClickListener {
    val button2 = findViewById(R.id.btn2ID) as Button
    button2.performClick()
}
```

Replace `R.id.btn1ID` and `R.id.btn2ID` with their respective id(a).

**Reference:** [performClick()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#performClick())

---

You could also create a utility function to use it without making redundant variables like this:

```kotlin
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")  
fun Activity.findButtonById(@IdRes res : Int) : Button =
    findViewById(res) as Button

// and then in your create method of activity:
findButtonById(R.id.btn1ID).setOnClickListener {
    findButtonById(R.id.btn2ID).performClick()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. Unfortunately I find that performClick() does the same as callOnClick() and doesn't change the pressed state

Comment: @matparrott android documentation says, it `Performs all normal actions associated with clicking: reporting accessibility event, playing a sound, etc.`, there could have been some issue with your code, could you post your code?

Comment: After more study you are correct, the issue is that Android implements the click so fast it doesn't register on screen. Therefore I believe I need some form of delay.

Answer (score 0):

Try performClick() method like below:

```
fun onTwo(view: View) 
{
    button1.performClick()
}
```

Comment: performClick() seems to be doing the same as callOnClick and not changing the pressed state

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing this issue using coroutines in the end as such:

```
fun onTwo(view: View){
                GlobalScope.async{
                    delay(100)
                    button1.isPressed = false
                    GlobalScope.cancel()
                }
                button1.setPressed(true)
                button1.performClick()

            }
```